# Java MergeSort algorithm unidentifiable error

Tags: java, mergesort

I am playing with the MergeSort algorithm with ArrayLists, for some reason, the wrong value is assigned to my variable. For example, if I put in an arraylist with 4,5,4,2,1, it comes out as 1,2,4,5,4. I've just graduated from middle school and would like to play with Java over the summer. Can anyone please help me out?

```
import java.util.*;
public class MergeSort{

public ArrayList c;
private Comparable tempLargest;

public MergeSort()
{

}

public void merge (ArrayList <Comparable> a,    ArrayList <Comparable> b, ArrayList <Comparable> c) {
    int i2 = 0;
    int i1 = 0;
    c.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(a.size(), b.size());i++){
        if(a.size()+b.size() != c.size()){
            if (i2 >= b.size()){
                while(i<a.size()){
                    c.add(a.get(i));
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            } else if (i1 >= a.size()){
                while(i<b.size()){
                    c.add(b.get(i));
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            } else if (a.get(i1).compareTo(b.get(i2)) < 0){
                tempLargest = b.get(i2);
                while(i1 < a.size() && a.get(i1).compareTo(tempLargest)<=0 ){
                    c.add(a.get(i1));
                    i1++;
                }
                c.add(tempLargest);
                i2++;
            } else if (a.get(i1).compareTo(b.get(i2)) >= 0){
                tempLargest = a.get(i1);
                while(i2 < b.size() && b.get(i2).compareTo(tempLargest)<=0){
                    c.add(b.get(i2));
                    i2++;
                }
                c.add(tempLargest);
                i1++;
            } 
        }
    }        
}

public void mergeSort(ArrayList <Comparable> ary){
   ArrayList a = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
   ArrayList b = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
   ArrayList c = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
   int n = ary.size();
   if (n == 1){
   } else if (n ==2 ){
       if (ary.get(0).compareTo(ary.get(1))>0){
           Comparable temp = ary.get(0);
           ary.set(0, ary.get(1));
           ary.set(1, temp);
       }
   }else{ // divide list into two halves           
        int mid = (n+1)/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(i<mid){
                a.add(ary.get(i));
            }
            else{
                b.add(ary.get(i));
            }
        } 
        mergeSort(a);
        mergeSort(b); 
        merge(a,b,c);
        ary = c;
   } 
}
}
```

Comment: +1 for your plans to play with Java in the summer.

Comment: ary = c; <-- uhm, what is that supposed to do? Java passes parameters by value, not reference. Hint: start to play with a unit test framework and test your code, you may spot the error this way ;) Use [TestNG](http://testng.org) for instance.

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work, I get the expected output. The only problem is what fge mentioned, you have to replace the values in "ary", the assignment doesn't work because Java doesn't allow passing by reference.

Comment: I think you should put some print-outs in merge function, to find out what arrays you are merging and what output You get on every steep of algorithm

Comment: Thanks to all of you who replied! I did a few tests on passing by value vs passing by reference and that was the problem. I just did a deep copy and it worked.